# Display only a number of elements in chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have the necessity to display a big amount of data that I collect from a sensor (accelerometer data) in a chart. The problem is that the display is fixed, so all the data are displayed and the visualization is compressed after a certain number o sample acquired.

I would like to know if there is a modality for displaying for example the last 100 sample.

```
this.chart1.Series["AccX"].Points.AddY(val);
```

With this command I add a point to the chart when I acquire a sample (acceleration value). I need to display only the last samples (for example the last 200 points) in order to display the data better..

Comment: What UI framework are you using? Also, specify what you have succeeded to do and what you didn't

Comment: The framework is Microsoft .NET 4.5, I have implemented all the functions, I'M abel to display all the sample acquired, I need to display only the last samples in order to improve the visualization of the data

Comment: Ui framework - WPF, winforms, ASP.NET. I have no way to help you without more details. Also, specify what part of getting the last samples you are having trouble with.

Comment: sorry....Windows Forms. I explain better: this.chart1.Series["AccX"].Points.AddY(val); with this command I add a point to the chart when I acquire a sample (acceleration value). I need to display only the last samples (for example the last 200 points) in order to display the data better

Comment: Is it acceptable to delete the first points when more come in?

Comment: yes TaW, I solved with your suggestion:   this.chart1.Series["AccX"].Points.RemoveAt(0);